# HashMap and ArrayList order

Tags: java

I have `HashMap` and `ArrayList` I am adding data wih following code:

```
conversationsMap.put(sendName,new Conversation(receiverName,currentTime));
conversationsList=new ArrayList<Conversation>(conversationsMap.values());
```

I have an method for get `currentTime` like this:

```
conversation.getTime();
```

I want to order `conversationsList` by `currentTime` with this code they are not ordering.`conversationsList` should be like this:

`1)currentTime:10`

`2)currentTime:9`

`2)currentTime:8`

```
...
```

How can i achive this ? I guess I need to use a loop for get values then add to `conversationsList`

Comment: You will have to write a custom comparator for this and use it in your list

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class CustomComparator<T extends Conversation> implements Comparator<Conversation>{
        public int compare(Conversation loBean1, Conversation loBean2) {

    if(obj1.getTime()<obj2.getTime()) {
        return -1;
    } else if(obj1.getTime()>obj2.getTime()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0
    }
        }
    }

Collections.sort(conversationsList, new CustomComparator<Conversation>());
```

Comment: Cannot invoke compareTo(long) on the primitive type long  How can i resolve this ?

Comment: Thank you it is working but It is ordering by ASC I need to order by DESC

Comment: I guess you are looking for an way to do what is required and not the exact answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement the Comparable Interface.. And do something like this.

```
public class Conversation implements Comparable<Conversation>
```

{

```
int currentTime;

public int getCurrentTime()
{
    return currentTime;
}

public void setCurrentTime(int currentTime)
{
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Conversation o)
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (this.currentTime > o.getCurrentTime())
    {
        ret = 1;
    }
    else if (this.currentTime < o.getCurrentTime())
    {
        ret = -1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use it in one place then you may create the comparator on fly

```js
conversationsMap.put(sendName,new Conversation(receiverName,currentTime));
conversationsList=new ArrayList<Conversation>(conversationsMap.values());

Collections.sort(conversationsList, new Comparator<Conversation>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Conversation obj1, Conversation obj2)
    {
        if(obj1.getTime()<obj2.getTime()) {
            return -1;
        } else if(obj1.getTime()>obj2.getTime()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
});
```

which is some time convenient for small task. but if you are writing big project and long time code maintaining is there. you might use the previous answer provided.
for quick solution: